# Math.random won't randomize number 9 whenever it has to be assigned to last array slot

Tags: java, arrays, random

My code creates an array of size 10, it randoms numbers from 0 to 9 to fit in each slot. The problem comes when the number 9 is not picked until the last space. Math.random keeps randomizing numbers but it will never pick the number 9. I ran the program for about 1 minute and it never picked it.

Here is my program

```
public class GenerateRandomNumbers{

// main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int aSize = 10;
        int[] a = new int[aSize];//setting size of array
        for(int i = 0; a.length > i; i++){//looping through the whole array
            a[i] =  (int)(Math.random()*9) + 1;//assigning random number to each slot of array
            System.out.println("assign " + a[i] + " to i" + i);

            //looping through filled array slots.
            for(int k = i-1; -1 < k; k--){
                System.out.println("Check if " +  a[i] + " i"+ i + " = " + a[k]+ " k"+ k  );

                //if not unique give a new number
                if(a[i] == a[k]){
                    System.out.println("CHANGE HERE");
                    a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9) + 0;
                    System.out.println("assign " + a[i] + " to " + i);
                    k = i;//reset loop so it checks all over again

                }
            }
            System.out.println("ACCEPT");
        }
        for(int i = 0; a.length > i; i++){
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what is causing the bug?

Comment: `a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9) + 0;` - read that carefully.

Comment: Thanks my friend !

Answer (score 0):

Your line `a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*9) + 0;` is different from the time you used Math.random() above. Above you said `(int)(Math.random()*9) + 1`, that will give you a random number in the range of [1,9].

`(int)(Math.random()*9) + 0` will never evaluate to 9, its range is [0,8].

Comment: Thanks my friend !

Comment: you're welcome! feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem.